# Unable to clone Git in SAP cloud jenkins server

Tags: git, jenkins, cloud, sap-business-technology-platform

I uploaded jenkins war in SAP cloud platform and I can create users, install plugins everything but I am unable to clone the GIT URL.
I get an error saying

> **Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command:  ls-remote -h**

The same jenkins war works fine in my local system using localhost:8080.
So some one help me what exactly I am missing here and what's the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: need info here. How are you accessing the repo? With username password or with ssh key or any other method?

Comment: Also, check if Git and GitLab plugins are installed on that instance of Jenkins.

Comment: Accessing using username and password to login..All Git Plugins are installed

Answer (score 0):

May be something to do with the git?

Run `which git`

And paste the result or path here: Manage Jenkins > Configure System settings. In the Git section **Path to Git executable**.

Comment: Since it is in SAP Cloud we donot have console to run "which git".

Comment: There's always a way my friend. Just create a test job where u can you execute shell command to have your things done.